# How to update Java HashTable?

Tags: java, hashtable

I have two Hashtables and one LinkedList in order like:

```
Hashtable<Character, Hashtable<String, LinkedList<String>>> hashTab = new Hashtable(); 
Hashtable<String, LinkedList<String>> string_list = new Hashtable();
LinkedList<String> data_list = new LinkedList();
```

Now i have a function through which i am passing values in the hashtables and linkedlist

```
public String createPlayerAccount(String FirstName, String LastName, int Age, String Username, String Password, String IPAddress)
{
    char username_first_char = Username.charAt(0);

    try
    {
        boolean username_exists = hashTab.get(username_first_char).containsKey(Username);
        if(!username_exists)
        {
            String data_string = FirstName + " " + LastName + " " + Age + " " + Password + " " + IPAddress + playerStatus; //Pass user details to a string
            data_list.add(data_string);  //Add user details to the linked list
            string_list.put(Username, data_list);
            hashTab.put(username_first_char, string_list);
            return("Dear " + FirstName + ",  You have successfully registered");
        }
        else
        {
            return("Username already exists");
        }   
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        String data_string = FirstName + " " + LastName + " " + Age + " " + Password + " " + IPAddress +" "+ playerStatus; //Pass user details to a string
        data_list.add(data_string);  //Add user details to the linked list
        string_list.put(Username, data_list);
        hashTab.put(username_first_char, string_list);
        return("Username successfully added \n ");
    }
}
```

The playerStatus is set to 0 by default. Now i am creating another function for Signin() in which i want the value of playerStatus to be updated to 1. What should i do?

Signin():

```
public String playerSignIn(String Username, String Password, String IPAddress)
{
    char username_first_char = Username.charAt(0);
    try
    {
        String user_profile;
        boolean username_exists = hashTab.get(username_first_char).containsKey(Username);
        if(username_exists)
        {
            playerStatus = "1";
            //String data_string = Password + " " + IPAddress +" "+ playerStatus; //Pass user details to a string
            //data_list.add(data_string);  //Add user details to the linked list
            //string_list.put(Username, data_list);
            //hashTab.put(username_first_char, string_list);  //Add user details to the linked list
            //return();
            //hashTab.put(username_first_char, string_list);
            //user_profile = hashTab.get(username_first_char).get(Username).get(0);
            return(user_profile);
            /*String data_string = Username + " " + Password + " " + IPAddress +" "+ "1"; //Pass user details to a string
            data_list.add(data_string);  //Add user details to the linked list
            string_list.put(Username, data_list);
            hashTab.put(username_first_char, string_list); 

            String get_user_data = hashTab.get(username_first_char).get(Username).get(0);
            String[] user_record = get_user_data.split(" ");
            String users_status = user_record[5];*/

            //return("User status updated: " + user_record[5]);
        }
        else
        {
            return("Invalid username or password");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return("PAWNED");
    }
}
```

NOTE: This is the server side of the code. I am making a Client-Server distributed System.

Comment: Why use `Hashtable` instead of `HashMap` or `ConcurrentHashMap`?

Comment: If this "hashTab" is intended for some sort of acceleration: Remove it. It is not necessary. I also assume that you don't really need the "data_list". If you need it, explain why. But most importantly: Dont mess all this information (FirstName, LastName, Age, Password, IPAddress and playerStatus) into a String! Instead, create a class summarizing this information. Then the update of the playerStatus will become trivial, anyhow

Comment: I have to added threading that do no reflect iterations at real time but any ways what could be the solution for this?

Comment: @Marco13 Its a Distributed System, so have to adjust it any how.

Comment: Where is the playerStatus to update? I could not see any prior/default playerStatus to update.

Comment: The fact that it is a distributed system seems fairly unrelated to the problem. And frankly: The code seems rather messy, and it is not clear what your goal is and how it may be achieved without breaking anything...

Comment: I made it public - Didnt share the whole code but the public variable String playerStatus="0". And once the user logs in that is when the Signin  function is called i want the playerStatus="1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to create a POJO (object class) that will hold information about a given player.  I'd name that class Player.  If you need to have a string with the information about the player, for sending to the clients, just have a toString() method on the Player class.

When I developer multiplayer games, on the server side I usually use a ConcurrentHashMap to store the information.  If the messaging system you are using needs hashtable then you will have headaches with synchronization, which can cause deadlocks if you don't know what you are doing.

Start refactoring your code.  After you are using the Player class, the code should be much more readable, and you should be able to spot where another POJO might be useful too.